# 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<User>' in FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to determine if the user is logged in (Flutter Firebase) using FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser, and then return LoginScreen or Dashboard, but getting an error. I tried to write code based on instructions from FirebaseFlutter, but those seem to be deprecated...

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
            /// is because there is a user already logged
            return Dashboard();
          }

          /// Other way there is no user logged.
          return LoginScreen();
        });
  }
```

I'm getting an error in the 3rd line `future: ...` that stands for `The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<User>'`. Please may anyone explain to me how should I do this, and what I'm doing wrong?
I tried to pass that in function `()=>` but it still does not work...
Currently using firebase_auth: 0.20 and firebase_core 0.7

Comment: A `FutureBuilder` takes a future. `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is not a future. Not only will `FutureBuilder` accept something that isn't a future, but if you don't have a future to wait on in the first place, that makes `FutureBuilder` redundant.

Comment: Use this:                                                                         ```return FutureBuilder<User?>(
      future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is not a Future. It directlty returns the current `User` if they are currently signed-in, or `null` if not.

Try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null ? Dashboard() : LoginScreen();
}
```

Though, be aware that it might be null first when you refresh the page.

ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html

---

Instead, you may have a look at `Stream<User> authStateChanges ()`.

Ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html

Answer (score 13):

This is because `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` return `User` and `FutureBuilder` expect `future`, To fix this you have two options:

- Use this syntax :  `future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),`, this will convert `User` to ```Future
- Check if `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is `null` and return the convenient widget.

Comment: helpful, thanks a lot.